# How to update secret values of secret manger in CDK?

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-secrets-manager, aws-cdk-typescript

My secret manager is created with credential of RDS in CDK, with **DatabaseCluster** and credential param in it. Now i want to update some value in that secretmanager.

How can i update secret value of secret manager in CDK?

Comment: Please add a minimal version of the relevant code as an edit.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a great way to do this, and that's by design. Anything you put in the CDK *has* to be in your CFN template, and then it's no longer secret.

You'll need to find a process outside of the CDK and CFN to update those values.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, if you inject the secret as a string in your CDK code, it will show up in the complied CloudFormation output.

There are a hot debate about this topic [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/5810)

I solve this problem by update the secret by AWS CLI

```
aws secretsmanager put-secret-value --secret-id your_secret_arn --secret-string your_secret
```